# How to write a DbContext Class.

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, asp.net-mvc-3

If I have a database named STOREitems , and I have a table in that database titles PRICES, and the models name is Price would I write it something like this?

```
public class STOREitemsDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Price> PRICES { get; set; }
}
```

I worked through an MVC tutorial and now I am trying to do things on my own with already existing databases that I have access too. The tutorial didn't explain how to write a DB context class it simply gave it to me and stated what it does.

Comment: Do you use *Code First*? If so, it looks ok.

Comment: Add an `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` item to your project.  When it asks, select `Code First From Database`.  It'll generate your DbContext and classes for you, and you can get an idea of what's going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use an existing database, then you need to turn off database initialization on your context.

```
public class StoreItemsContext : DbContext
{
    public StoreItemsContext()
        : base("YourConnectionStringName")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<StoreItemsContext>(null);
    }

    // DbSet's here
    public DbSet<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}
```

*Note: classes and property names should be camel-cased with the first letter capitalized.*

If your table name doesn't match the default Entity Framework convention of the entity class name, pluralized. Then you need to tell EF explicitly what table to map the data to/from:

```
[Table("PRICES")]
public class Price
{
    ...
}
```

You actually should be fine without that for this particular entity, but I used it for the purposes of providing an example.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a constructor for the context, where you set the connectionstring

Like:

```
public class STOREitemsDBContext : DbContext
{
    public STOREitemsDBContext():base("Connectionstring")           
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Price> PRICES { get; set; }
}
```

In the App.config you have to add a connectionstring like:

And now you can save your values in DB

```
STOREitemsDBContext sidbcontext = new STOREitemsDBContext();
Price price = new Price(10.10);
sidbcontext.Price.Add(price);
sidbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

that should work for you